# Rotation of the camera around an object in an inclined orbit in OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0

Tags: android, matrix, trigonometry

To rotate the camera around an object along the abscissa axis (X), I use the following code:

```
private float k = 0f;
...
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Math.PI * 2 - full rotation
    k = (k >= Math.PI * 2) ? 0.0f : k + 0.01f; // gradually rotate the camera
    float radius = 2.6f;

    float x = (float) (radius * Math.cos(k));
    float z = (float) (radius * Math.sin(k));
    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, x, 0, z, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    ...
}
```

To rotate the camera around an object along the ordinate axis (Y):

```
...
float y = (float) (radius * Math.cos(k));
float z = (float) (radius * Math.sin(k));
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0, y, z, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
...
```

But I don't understand how to rotate the camera around an object along an inclined axis. What is the ratio between x, y, z should be in this case?

Thank you for any comment / response!

Note: The center of the object coincides with the point where the camera is looking (0,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    ...
    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 5f,
        0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    Matrix.rotateM(viewMatrix, 0, angle1, x:1, y:0, z:0);
    Matrix.rotateM(viewMatrix, 0, angle2, x:0, y:1, z:0);
    ...
}
```